# cannot assign value of type UIDatePicker to type string? Swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have this error at line "AvailableDayTextField.text = datePicker"

```
@IBOutlet var AvailableDayTextField: UITextField!
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

func createDatePicker(){
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done , target: nil , action: nil)
    toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
    AvailableDayTextField.text = datePicker
}
```

Comment: where you show the date picker in your class

Comment: in func ViewDidLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like

on your `ViewDidLoad` set like

```
 datePicker.date = NSDate()
datePicker.datePickerMode = .Date
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dateTextField), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
AvailableDayTextField.inputView = datePicker
```

and call the fucntion as

```
func dateTextField(sender: AnyObject) {
var picker = (AvailableDayTextField.inputView as! UIDatePicker)
picker.maximumDate = NSDate()
var dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
var eventDate = picker.date
dateFormat.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
var dateString = dateFormat.stringFromDate(eventDate)
AvailableDayTextField.text = "\(dateString)"
}
```

Comment: how can i make it disappear after choosing date

Comment: AvailableDayTextField. resignFirstResponder()